# A tricky problem on permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume that $x_1, x_2, ......, x_{10}$ is a permutation of $1, 2, ......, 10$.

For $1\leq m < n \leq 10$, we have $x_m+m\leq x_n+n$.

Try to find the number of those permutations.

We can find that the inequality is equivalent to: $$x_n-1\leq x_{n+1}$$ but I can't get further more.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalize the problem for any natural $k$ instead of $10$. Call a permutation $x=(x_1,\dots, x_k)$ of numbers $1,\dots, k$ *slowly decreasing* if $x_n-1\le x_{n+1}$ for each $1\le n\le k-1$. Let
$SD_k$ be the set of all slowly decreasing permutations of numbers $1,\dots, k$ and $s_k=|SD_k|$.

Let $x\in SD_k$. If $x_n=k$ then the inequality consecutively implies that $x_{n+i}=k-i$ for each positive integer $i$ such that $n+i\le k$. Then $(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})\in SD_{n-1}$. This yields us a recurrent formula
$$s_k=\sum_{n=1}^n s_{n-1},$$
where we put $s_0=1$.

Thus $s_k-s_{k-1}=s_{k-1}$
for each $k\ge 2$. Simple induction shows that $s_k=2^{k-1}$ for each $k\ge 1$.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oops, I am sorry. Fixed. Thanks for your care.